# FastAPI Sqlalchemy get lastest result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have setup my first Python FastAPI but getting stuck. I have a function that query some results. The following function query the first entry in the database on a specific date. Now I want the last entry on a date or all results sort by highest id but how do i do this?

```py
def get_workday(db: Session, workday_date: date):
    return db.query(DBWorkday).where(DBWorkday.date == workday_date).first()
```

full code:

```py
from datetime import date
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List
from sqlalchemy import Date, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker, Session
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer

app = FastAPI()

# SqlAlchemy Setup
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///../db/database.db'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True, future=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()


# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

# A SQLAlchemny ORM


class DBWorkday(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'workdays'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    date = Column(Date)
    start_time = Column(String(4))
    end_time = Column(String(4))
    type = Column(String, nullable=True)
    location = Column(String, nullable=True)


Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# Workday Pydantic model


class Workday(BaseModel):
    date: date
    start_time: str
    end_time: str
    type: Optional[str] = None
    location: Optional[str] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

# Methods for interacting with the database


def get_workday(db: Session, workday_date: date):
    return db.query(DBWorkday).where(DBWorkday.date == workday_date).first()


@app.get('/workday/{date}')
def get_workday_view(date: date, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return get_workday(db, date)
```

Comment: So what's your definition of "the last result"? The one with the last `end_time` or the last `start_time`? What is the content of the `end_time` field? The one with the highest `id`?

Comment: Sorry you're right that's not entirely clear in my question. What I mean by last is the last entry in the database so highest ```id```

Comment: `return db.query(DBWorkday).where(DBWorkday.date == workday_date).order_by(DBWorkday.id.desc()).first()` ?

Comment: Yes! thanks so much I was spending hours to find this. It is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
return db.query(DBWorkday).where(DBWorkday.date == workday_date).order_by(DBWorkday.id.desc()).first()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.